# I am trying to change the content of a an html element rendered by React.js using onClick. But this code doesn't seem to work

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code. The para with className "para" isn't changing. How to check if the function is being called?

```
  var Banner = React.createClass({
    onBannerClick : function(){
      document.getElementsByClassName('para').innerHTML = "Clicked it";
   },
   render:function(){
     return(
     <p className='para' onClick={this.onBannerClick}>Click this</p>
   )
   }
  });
  ReactDOM.render(<Banner/>,
    document.getElementById('atom')
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react you don't modify the DOM directly. You change the model (props or state, and react re-renders the component to reflect the new model:

```
var Banner = React.createClass({
    onBannerClick: function(){ // change the model
        this.setState({
            clicked: !this.state.clicked
        });
    },
    render:function(){
        return(
            <p onClick={this.onBannerClick}>
                {
                    this.state.clicked && "Clicked it" // according to the model the text is displayed or not
                }
            </p>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Banner/>,
    document.getElementById('atom')
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the className to id, and it seems to work. Why so?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it works or not. React controls the DOM, and if you manage it manually, you have to know when react finished, and you'll have to clean up manually. This is ok if you desperately need a jQuery plugin, but for most things, doing it the react way will be more performant, and much easier.

Answer (score 0):

However this code is working

```
  var Banner = React.createClass({
    onBannerClick : function(){
      document.getElementsByClassName('para').innerHTML = "Clicked it";
   },
   render:function(){
     return(
     <p className='para' onClick={this.onBannerClick}>Click this</p>
   )
   }
  });
  ReactDOM.render(<Banner/>,
    document.getElementById('atom')
  )
```